# Checking internet connection in PhoneGap app

Tags: ios, cordova, network-connection

I am trying to figure out if the device is connected to the internet when the app is started.
As far as I have read, the javascript code should be something like this:

```
function isOnline() {
    var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;
    if (networkState == Connection.NONE) {
        return false;
    };
    return true;
}
```

I have only tried it on iOS so far.
Unfortunately, navigator.network is undefined.

I know that I have to add the network module in the config.xml file.
According to the PhoneGap page (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html),
this is the way I did it:

```
<feature name="NetworkStatus">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVConnection" />
</feature>

<feature name="NetworkStatus">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager" />
</feature>
```

Does anybody know what I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

try this one.

install this cordova plugin here.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information

and add this code into js file

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
// device APIs are available
//

function onDeviceReady() {
    isOnline();
}

function isOnline() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN] = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI] = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G] = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G] = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G] = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL] = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE] = 'No network connection';
    if ((states[networkState]) == states[Connection.NONE]) {
        alert('No Internet Connection. Click OK to exit app');
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
function checkConnection() {
        return navigator.connection.type === "none" || navigator.network.connection.type === null ||
                navigator.connection.type === "unknown" ? false : true;
    }
```

And remember to check this AFTER device ready event has fired.

Comment: Thank you, but navigator.connection.type is undefined too under Android and iOS. I do the check after device read has fired.

Comment: what phonegap version do you use?

Comment: I use 3.3.0. I figured out that checking a server with XMLHttpRequest works, but simply using a property would be much more elegant.

Comment: yes, well, Im using the code above, although it's in phonegap 2.9. Did you set the permission in android manifest file? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: At the moment I don't have an android manifest file. What about iOS? Would I need such a file there as well?

Comment: You do have the android manifest file, its called AndroidManifest.xml, you wouldnt run app if you didnt have that file. iOS does not have that.